# KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer adds initial null bytes (00 00 00 00 0C 7B) to the record value

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

Using the following Spring-Boot properties

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: "ssl"
  kafka:
    producer:
      client-id: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_CLIENT_ID:kafka-producer}
      bootstrap-servers: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS:localhost:9092}
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer
```

the published JSON values starts with null bytes (`00 00 00 00 0C 7B` in Hex).
This results in an invalid JSON string (e.g. when displayed in Offset-Explorer).

The `@Configuration` class I'm using is as simple as

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:kafka.yaml"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:kafka-ssl.yaml"),
})
public class KafkaProducerConfiguration {
    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @Bean("producer-factory")
    public <T> ProducerFactory<String, T> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(this.kafkaProperties.getProducer().buildProperties(null));
    }

    @Bean("kafka-template")
    public <T> KafkaTemplate<String, T> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, T> producerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    }
}
```

and then I use the private final KafkaTemplate<String, T> kafkaTemplate; to publish a Java object on a topic.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaProducerServiceImpl<T> implements KafkaProducerService<T> {

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, T> kafkaTemplate;

    @Override
    public void send(String topic, Function<T, String> key, T message) throws KafkaException {
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key.apply(message), message);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something in the configuration properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected for that Serializer. [Confluent docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format)

> results in an invalid JSON string (e.g. when displayed in Offset-Explorer

Offset Explorer doesn't have **JSONSchema** support in its [Registry integration](https://offsetexplorer.com/documentation/avro.html), last I checked. Spring-Kafka has its own [JSONSerializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/serdes.html#json-serde) class that you would want to use instead of anything from Confluent, assuming you want JSON data without using the Schema Registry.

Using the Schema Registry will always send binary encoded data with a starting null byte

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought I was doing something wrong.
I'm using the Schema Registry so I can't do otherwise.
Then, is this format supported only by the Confluent KafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer?
I mean, will this force other Kafka consumers (e.g. default Spring-Kafka) to use only the Confluent deserializer?

Comment: That's correct. There are probably other Kafka UI tools to read JSONSchema data, too